# Error when trying to install gpaw

Tags: python, pip, physics

When I try to run

`sudo pip3 install -U gpaw`

I get the following error

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-n4w3sszk/gpaw/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1nhmwzay-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-n4w3sszk/gpaw/
```

with python 2 i do

`sudo pip install -U gpaw`

I then get:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tUJx3k/gpaw/
```

can i change anything in the command to make it run? or do i need a more complicated solution?

Comment: Have you followed [installation instructions](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/install.html) and installed all necessary libraries (ASE and others)?

Comment: I have (Ase, numpy, script and matplotlib) from pip, BLAS should be in Solus (as far as I am aware) I might lack libxc, I'll look at that in a moment.